# Electromagnetic field strength tensor fermion couplings

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

The electromagnetic field strength tensor, $F_{\mu\nu}$, contains the electric and magnetic fields as its components. In that case, would one be able to use $F_{\mu\nu}$ to describe specifically the electric (or magnetic) interaction between two fermions? In other words, what would be the Lagrangian to describe the interactions of two fermions via $F_{\mu\nu}$? How can one show whether the force is attractive or repulsive?

Comment: See equation (1) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0406355).

Comment: Hi @Ghoster, ok. Thanks. How can one know whether the force is attractive or repulsive?

Comment: I assume that figuring that out would require a complicated QED calculation. Since this is a dipole-dipole interaction, my hunch is that it could be either attractive or repulsive depending on how the two spins are oriented.